# Is this a bug in codeblock indention?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, formatting, markdown

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66029/31033

Is this a bug or am I using a feature I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 8):

Markdown thinks you're still inside the bullet list, so it thinks you've just started another paragraph inside the list.

- To add a code block inside the bullet list, you'd need 8 spaces of indentation instead of the usual four.
- But I think you just wanted to have a code block after the bullet list, so you need something to indicate that the bullet list has ended. The simplest solution is to add an HTML comment, i.e. simply  `<!-- -->`, without indentation after the bullet list and before the code block. (I've made this edit for you so you can see what it looks like).

Comment: thanks. is the `<!-- -->` kind of feature? Or is it more of an workaround?

Comment: @Zaibis I'd say it's a workaround, but a useful one. You can also use it to have two separate code blocks without a paragraph in between.